# sphere with waves on the surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I am working on surface waves on a curved surfaces and I need to draw a 3D sphere with sinusoidal waves on its surface, waves should start from the top and end in bottom,  I have no idea how to do it. 
here is what I want but in a half sphere (look at figure b). I want a schematic figure like that, can anyone help?
http://bvukasinovic.gatech.edu/modes.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you post a MWE (minimal working example) of what you've already achieved?

Comment: Maybe TikZ (2D)?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you want... I do not know physics. But as long as you can parameterize the surface as r=(θ,φ) you can draw it with `tikz-3dplot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\node{Start:\currenttime};

    \def\n{10}
    \def\m{10}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\n}{
        \tikz[tdplot_main_coords,line width=0,line join=round]{
            \useasboundingbox(-25,-25)(25,25);
            \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{500}{20}
            {10+.5*sin(\m*\tdplottheta+360*\i/\n)}
            {black}{\m*\tdplottheta+360*\i/\n}{}{}{}
        }
    }

    \tikz\node{End:\currenttime};
\end{document}
```